# Oracle job scheduler not working

Tags: oracle

i create a job in oracle which will run in every minute but the problem is job is create successfully but not run on time

```
execute PACKAGE_BATCH.USP_TERMIANTE_SUSPENSION;
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
            job_name => '"LTR"."TERMINATE_SUSPENSION_JOB"',
            job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
            job_action => 'LTR.PACKAGE_BATCH.USP_TERMINATE_SUSPENSION',
            number_of_arguments => 0,
            start_date => sysdate,
            repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;BYMINUTE=1',
            end_date => NULL,
            enabled => TRUE,
            auto_drop => TRUE,
            comments => 'Terminate Suspension When End Date is equal to Current Date');

            DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute
            ( name => '"LTR"."TERMINATE_SUSPENSION_JOB"',
            attribute => 'job_action', 
            value => 'LTR.PACKAGE_BATCH.USP_TERMINATE_SUSPENSION');

            DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => '"LTR"."TERMINATE_SUSPENSION_JOB"', 
             attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_RUNS);

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
             name => '"LTR"."TERMINATE_SUSPENSION_JOB"');
END;
```

Comment: what times does it run?

Comment: You sure the job would finish in a minute?

Comment: @kevinsky every minute !

Comment: I think you want it to run every minute. Look at the logs, how often does it really run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FREQ=MINUTELY;BYMINUTE=1
```

This will make the job run at every "1"st minute. So 12:01, 1:01, 2:01 etc.

If you need to make it run every minute - `FREQ=MINUTELY` is sufficient or you can add `BYSECOND=0` if you want to ensure it runs at exactly 12:01:00, 12:02:00, 12:03:00 etc.

Comment: Note: it won't guarantee that it will run at "exactly" 0 seconds - that's just the earliest time the job will run. It may take a little while for the database to pick up the job.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple, see these examples:

- **Every minute**

Repeat interval using calendaring syntax.

```
'freq=minutely;'
```

Repeat interval using dates and timestamps.

```
'sysdate + 1/24/60'
'systimestamp + 1/24/60'

'sysdate + interval ''1'' minute'
'systimestamp + interval ''1'' minute'
```

- **Every minute, on the minute**

Repeat interval using calendaring syntax.

`'freq=minutely; bysecond=0;'`

Repeat interval using dates and timestamps.

```
'trunc(sysdate, ''MI'') + 1/24/60'
'trunc(systimestamp, ''MI'') + 1/24/60'

'trunc(sysdate, ''MI'') + interval ''1'' minute'
'trunc(systimestamp, ''MI'') + interval ''1'' minute'
```

More example here http://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g.php#every_minute